pronoun, which requires a verb to complement it
I have a question regarding my PTE exam and my Write Essay template. In the following sentence, is it correct to use "what" without "is/was/had been" before "elaborated"?

"..., after analyzing what elaborated above, I firmly believe..."

Should it be "what elaborated above" or "what was elaborated above"?

How would you go about discovering the answer to this question yourself, if this forum or others like it did not exist?

It is an active v. passive difference; "was elaborated" is a passive construction.
Only the passive makes sense here.  A topic was elaborated by the author.  The verb "elaborated" isn't labile. You can't say "A topic elaborated". And so, in your sense, you need "what was elaborated above".


*after analyzing what elaborated above

We need a BE to form a complete noun phrase what [was] elaborated above:

after analyzing what [was] elaborated above

This is the same as

after analyzing that which was elaborated above

where the pronoun that is the antecedent of the relative clause
which was elaborated above.
